# How do I compile an seperate JS file with the Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm building a Vue application via the Vue CLI and I want to compile a stand alone JS file as well as the Vue solution.

What I want to see compiled is...

```
`-- dist
    |-- js
    |   |-- index.js
    |   |-- sdk.js
    |   `-- chunk-vendors.js
    |-- index.css
    |-- favicon.ico
    `-- index.html
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should run in terminal [npm run build](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages) for compile the project and you will get dist folder with index.html and main.js.